# How to make map of .class?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am new to Java Reflection and generics and I am trying to understand them. Here I came accros a problem. I can make Lists and maps of  or  and other stuff.. But can I make a map of Classes ?

I have for example this class

```
public class ClassA{}
public class ClassB extends ClassA{}
public class ClassC extends ClassA{}
```

and so on.. 
Now I want a map like this Map();
In this map I can put anyhing that extends from A. Thats good. But what if I want to store something like this:

```
ClassX extends ClassA... 
//some stuff
Map<String, ?????> customMapForTest = new HashMap<>();
customMapForTest.add("customKey", ClassX.class);
```

So I will have something like a map of templates of certain classes I want to use dependant on my settings.

Is something like this possible? How is it called if I want to store this kind of .class files in map ?

To get more into the situation I have my own application //Don't worry, this is not a public project or something.. just for experimenting. 
I have a file with some characters like this : X7WE2C3AD4A2
Just some random stuff. 
Now I have a file reader that reads each character and based on it it searches the map I created, takes the class of that file and creates new instance of that class and adds some values based on type.

example:

```
customMapForTesting.get("X").getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(int.class,String.class).newInstance(numberVariable, stringVariable);
```

I store that new instances to a different map and use it in some other stuff. 
Problem is I need all possible objects that are extending my template and I don't want to store instances inside the templateMap...

Comment: `Map<String, Class<?>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.Class` type is what you looking for

```
Map<String, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("string",String.class);
```

Just mind you, `int.class` is different from `Integer.class`

```
System.out.println(int.class.equals(Integer.class)); //false
System.out.println(int.class.equals(Integer.TYPE)); //true
```

Comment: I tried something like this before but i wrote it bad.. I got something like this :
Map<String, Class<?> extends ClassA).... now I discovered that it is writen like this : Class<? extends ClassA> ... But thanks anyway :-) 

I think that everyone knows difference between int and Integer... 
I used that for example and that was the first thing that came in mind. 
I read a lot of Java Wtf codes so I am avare of those but still I make stupid mistake like I did here..